# Shared line counter with \lstinputlisting

Tags: listings, line-numbering

Using the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) package, you can name your listings to make them share a line counter:

> On the other hand you can use firstnumber=auto and name your listings.
>   Listings with identical names (case sensitive!) share a line counter.

However, this only seems to work when the `lstlisting` environment is used, not when using `\lstinputlisting`. After a closer examination of the manual, this seems to be documented:

> `name=<name>`
>
> names a listing. Displayed **environment-listings** with the
>   same name share a line counter if firstnumber=auto is in effect.

I was wondering if anyone knows some kind of "trick" to share line counters across `\lstinputlisting`s.

Here is a MWE to demonstrate the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{numbers=left,firstnumber=auto}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[name=bar]
...
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[name=bar] %first line number is the last of previous listing + 1
...
\end{lstlisting}
\lstinputlisting[name=foo]{foo.c}
\lstinputlisting[name=foo]{foo.c} %first line number is 1
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am using the latest version if the `listings` package (TeXLive 2011) and it seems that the numbering does **not** resume in any of the cases.

Comment: @Peter: That's weird, I'm using the same version and it works for the environment case. Did you try my MWE verbatim?

Comment: Yep, just cut and pasted the given MWE. I also confirmed that I see identical behavior with TeXLive2010. I noticed the message `Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing on input line 10.` in the console though, so perhaps my problem is related to that.

Comment: Related Question: [Create a \lstnewenvironment that creates named listings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60867/create-a-lstnewenvironment-that-creates-named-listings/).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `name=foo, firstnumber=last` option to `\lstinputlisting` to obtain the desired results as shown in the yellow highlighted code:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.c}
  #include <stdio.h>
  void main()
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{numbers=left,firstnumber=auto}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[name=bar]
  first line
  second line
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[name=bar]
  third line (continued)
\end{lstlisting}

\lstinputlisting[name=foo,backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!20}]{foo.c}
\lstinputlisting[name=foo,backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!20}, firstnumber=last]{foo.c} %first line number is now 3
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Peter! Your example helped to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to @Peter's answer: if you use the `firstline`/`lastline` options, you have to put the option `firstnumber` as last, as in the code below; otherwise your second listing will start with line number 1 again.

```
\lstinputlisting[name=foo,firstline=1,lastline=2]{foo.c}
\lstinputlisting[name=foo,firstline=3,lastline=4, firstnumber=last]{foo.c} %first line number is now 3
```

(Tested with listings.sty - 2014/09/06 1.5e)