# Create a \lstnewenvironment that creates named listings

Tags: listings, environments

I am using the `\lstnewenvironment` to format a set of code listings in my document.

```
\lstnewenvironment{code}
    {\lstset{language=haskell,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
    firstnumber=auto
    }}
    {}
```

I would like to be able to give all these listings the same name, so that they will be continuously numbered, even if other listings (not using the `code` environment) are scattered in between them.

However I cannot add the `name` property using `\lstset`.  The top of page 11 of the listings manual indicates that there are certain properties that can only be set as options directly on the listing (and not in `\lstset`).  I suspect this is one of those properties.  So I would have to do

```
\begin{code}[name=main]
...
\end{code}
```

on every listing.  Is there some other way I can indicate that the `code` environment should always carry that `name` option?

Comment: By numbers, are you referring to line numbers (set using `name`), or listing numbers? Also, by virtue of minimal testing (and reflected in Peter's answer), you can set `name=main` as part of `\lstset`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to egreg, you can use a custom counter to keep track of the last line number and resume from there:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcounter{main}
\setcounter{main}{1}

\lstnewenvironment{code}[1][firstnumber=\themain,name=main]
  {\lstset{language=haskell,
           basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
           numbers=left,
           numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
           backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
           #1
          }
}
{\setcounter{main}{\value{lstnumber}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{code}
 foo bar first line
 foo bar second line
 foo bar third line
\end{code}

some text

\begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray!20}]
  some other non-code listing
\end{lstlisting}


\begin{code}
 listing continued
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, if I move `firstnumber=\themain` into `\lstset`.  I'm fairly certain `name=main` is simply being ignored -- which is ok -- using a separate counter that resets to `\lstcounter` handles the line numbering perfectly.

Comment: @David: Agreed, but specifying that as the first optional parameter allows you to override it if ever needed.

Answer (score 3):

Note that in `listings.sty`, `lstlisting` is defined by

```
\lstnewenvironment{lstlisting}[2][]
    {\lst@TestEOLChar{#2}%
     \lstset{#1}%
     \csname\@lst @SetFirstNumber\endcsname}
    {\csname\@lst @SaveFirstNumber\endcsname}
```

Copying the lines `\csname\@lst @SetFirstNumber\endcsname` and `\csname\@lst @SaveFirstNumber\endcsname` into your own `\lstnewenvironment` (after the appropriate `\makeatletter` trick) should work with the usual `name` key defined in `\lstset`. See it in the context of the following compilable example, borrowed from Peter Grill's answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\lstnewenvironment{code}[1][]
    {\lstset{language=haskell,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
    firstnumber=auto,
    name=main,
    #1}%
    \csname\@lst @SetFirstNumber\endcsname}
    {\csname\@lst @SaveFirstNumber\endcsname}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{code}
 foo bar first line
 foo bar second line
 foo bar third line
\end{code}

some text

\begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray!20}]
  some other non-code listing
\end{lstlisting}


\begin{code}
 listing continued
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you put together a compilable example that shows that this actually works. I tried and the numbering did not resume when this new environment was used a second time.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Compilable example now added. (Sorry, I should have done that in the first place!) I borrowed the example from your solution, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks, and it works great. Will be removing these comments soon.